# How do you create an optional variable that is assigned a function in Swift

Tags: swift, function, swift-optionals

I would like to create an optional variable that can be assigned a function ( or can be nil). I'm guessing it would look something like this but the following code does not compile.

```
var variableThatWillBeAssignedAFunction: {(Int) -> Int}?
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var variableThatWillBeAssignedAFunction: ((Int) -> Int)?
```

To make it more readable, you can also use a typealias:

```
typealias IntegerTransform = (Int) -> Int
var variableThatWillBeAssignedAFunction: IntegerTransform?
```

Comment: I was so close 

Comment: Haha yes it takes a while to get used to :) I edited my answer with a more readable way, maybe this will help.